# command line working but not working in shell script

Tags: shell, command-line

I use the following command to get the output (number tagged in the latest file):

```sh
 ls -lrt | tail -n1 |  awk -F'.' '{print $4}' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

but when I use the same command in a shell script and get the result in a variable `c`, I don't get the proper result.

My script:

```
#! /bin/sh

c=ls -lrt | tail -n1 |  awk -F'.' '{print $4}' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
echo $c
```

The error that shows when I execute is:

```
 -lrt: command not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing: trying to run a command with a per-command variable.

`VAR=foo ./somecommand.sh`

would run `./somecommand.sh` with `VAR` set to `foo`. But `VAR` would not be set for commands executed later.

Your example sets `c=ls` and tries to run `-lrt` - obviously this is neither found nor intended.

I assume you want to save the output to variable `c`.

You would use

```
c=`ls -lrt | tail -n1 | awk -F'.' '{print $4}' | grep -o '[0-9]+'`
echo "$c"
```

Modern shells use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` for command substitution, as nesting command substitution gets easier with this syntax.